# what essential material or ingredients in modern gunpowder that if changed to be expensive or rare, can ruin the evolution of advance/modern gun?

Tags: science-based, alternate-history, chemistry, materials, alternate-reality

as the title, what materials or ingredients in modern gunpowder that if change to be expensive or rare to get, can ruin the evolution of advance gun or can turn modern gun obsolete or undesirable ?

i know generally gunpowder is made of sulfur, saltpeter, and charcoal (which i learn that it is abundant in earth some even from poop or guano so its unlikely happen unless earth get a massive catastrope/apocalypse). but modern gunpowder have some different chemical so far as i know (so i want to know the chance).

as i mention its about the materials or ingredients, so answer that say it prone to explode/kill the user or human never found the right measure or dosage because they are backward/brainwashed due to religion,tradition, pride,moralit,humanity, etc is out of this question.

but answer that include reason or some chain reaction like supply and demand or something that quickly depleting such ingredient for non gunpowder stuff that make the modern gunpowder ingredient expensive or rare is acceptable.

outright entire nation outlawing the ingredient just for the sake of banning modern gunpowder or gun like banning missile use because it kill to much people or too gruesome or can destroy the earth is out of this question.

natural massive catastrope to eradicate the chemical or modern gunpowder ingredients is out of this question.

gun was invented but not the type in ww1 to ww2 it stuck before this era, and they know gun was practical or massively advantageous in battle or to kill.

feel free to edit the tag to the apropriate one because i dont know which tag is apropriate for my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern "gunpowder" isn't really a powder, it's only people call it that because it replaced black powder. Honestly, as long as you can make black powder, you can also make it, all you need is know-how. All you have to do is convert sulfur into sulfuric acid, saltpeter into nitric acid, and instead of charcoal, get cellulose. Usually, cellulose used for this is cotton, thus the modern "gunpowder" is also known as gun cotton, but it's possible to use other sources as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrocellulose#Munitions
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokeless_powder#Chemical_formulations

I should mention that nowadays, the mixtures used as "modern gunpowder" are more than just gun cotton, but even without advanced mixtures, gun cotton lets you do all you need to make modern repeating firearms(machine guns, bolt-action, semi auto and auto weapons, as well as long ranged howitzers/cannons/mortars).

Edit: Only feasible way to prevent modern type firearms from appearing while having black powder firearm is in my opinion to make it so that your society lacks advanced chemistry knowledge.

Comment: Just two comments - China had gunpowder for long time, but did not use it much for military weapons (so society could postpone developement of modern weapons a lot). Sulphur can be much more scare to find in alternate universe, so it would play the role of "rare" ingredience, especially, if most of it would be used to make "old proven" black powder and the rest is so expensive, that only few can be spend on some "impractical experiments". Anyway even modern weaponry could be based on blackpowder, with just much more need to cleaning.

Comment: Maybe you could restrict "primers" by having https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury(II)_fulminate unobtainable - so you would get stuck for long with flintlocks and similars

Comment: Yeah, primers are very important, but you could probably make wheelock based workarounds. It would have interesting effects on development of guns though.

Comment: @gilhad sulphur is the 10th most common element in the milky way. Handwaving it away seems dubious.

Comment: And Aluminium is 7. element on Earth, still it took long time to isolate it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium#History - so I can imagine, that there is a plenty sulphur IN alternative Earth, but just a small fraction is (relativly) simply obtainable in form, that could be used to make gunpowder (until advanced chemistry or advanced mining)

Comment: @gilhad have you looked into the reasons why aluminium is hard to separate, but why you can find sulphur in lumps on the earth's surface? The comparison is not reasonable.

Comment: Alright, I did some research and even without chemical primers, there are things such as electric primer that could be used(basically thin non-melting metal covered in guncotton, that ignites the load). Not having chemical primer would change modern weapons, but it wouldn't make advanced guns go away.

Comment: "your society lacks advanced chemistry knowledge" is the best answer since there is a variety of propellants that can be used. no one material can restrict them all.

Answer (score -2):

I see three interlinked possibilities, based on a quick read of [this review article](https://www.annualreviews.org/content/journals/10.1146/annurev-earth-060313-054802) :

1. Have a world populated by dangerous creatures that makes the mining or processing of sulfur difficult and dangerous, similar to the making of steel before the Bessemer process - it could be done, but was not generally economical to do so.  A comparable setting would be Pern and the Threadfall.  This would impact all mining, among other things; elemental sulfur must be dug for, and in the real world is often stumbled upon while in search of other things in the earth.
2. Have a highly foliated/faunated world where sulphur deposits are rare and valuable.  I base this on the 'sulphur cycle' being tied to a world that is either at or near a 'green peak, and so environmental CO2 and sulfates are low in abundance but not yet scarce.  A world abundant in plantlife with a robust hydrological cycle would not leave many deposits of organics like sulfur or salt evaporates of it.  It would be very easy to find or obtain nitrates, which would make Sulfur singularly valuable to any party or power who knew how to make and use Black Powder.
3. Have a (semi-)Mendeleevian, pre- or a-scientific understanding of the Periodic Table (I am presuming since you're on the topic of firearms, you're leaning on real chemistry and not magical macguffins).  Mendeleev was, in cultural context, an alchemist, just one who happened to be uncannily correct in his predictions when the scientific chemists came along and made independent discoveries that confirmed his predictions.
   Keep in mind that occluding the Scientific Method from a civilization is not a simple business; it fundamentally affects and is affected by many things, most notably religion (because, contrary to modern impressions, the Scientific Method was founded on Theism, not in spite of it).

Comment: Alchemist? Dmitri Ivanovich Mendeleev was a very distinguished chemist and a professor at the Saint Petersburg Technological Institute. He was awarded the [Davy Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Medal) in 1882, together with the German chemist [Lothar Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lothar_Meyer) "for their discovery of the periodic relations of the atomic weights". He was a [Foreign Member of the Royal Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellow_of_the_Royal_Society). He died in 1907; Humphry Davy had died in 1829, Berzelius had died in 1848, Kekulé had died in 1896...

Comment: @AlexP I'll take that on the chin.  Mendeleev made his predictions before a properly explanatory atomic theory had been developed, which paved the way for other (western) minds like Niels Bohr and Linus Pauling, which is what makes his predictions so remarkable.  If the Nobel Prize had been around in his time, he should have won it.

Comment: modern guns don't use sulfur, in fact they go through a lot of effort to keep it out of propellants.

Comment: I'll take that downvote since, according to https://www.compoundchem.com/2014/07/02/the-chemistry-of-gunpowder/ , sulphur isn't strictly necessary in modern smokeless powder; however the assertion that is has been eliminated from modern formulations is inaccurate.  I was focusing on black powder, which wasn't the asker's interest (kinda skipped over the word 'modern' ) .